# Direct Xorg/Xserver manipulation without Desktop Environment

Tags: xorg, gui, x-server, kiosk

I'd like to create a GUI kiosk application, and ideally avoid the need to install a desktop.

Is it possible to use Cairo/OpenGL to generate graphics in an application launched from the console without needing a Desktop Environment?

Answer (score 1):

X can work without a Desktop Environment or Window Manager. That's what you get if your login manager offers a "Failsafe" option.

Have a look at `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`. It may be enough to run `unset WINDOWMANAGER; startx` from the console to achieve this.